# Can a Muslim man marry a Hindu woman

Tags: nikah, sharia

Assalamualaikum. I'm a 26 year old muslim man who's been in a relationship with a non muslim woman (Hindu) for 4 years. We have committed zina and want to marry each other.
The woman wants to marry me by accepting Islam , but wants to practice Hinduism as well.
I plan to marry this woman first by reverting her to Islam and start teachings of Islam and and our Prophet PBUH after marriage.
I would like to know the possibilities and conditions on which I can marry this non muslim woman.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I would like to know more in detail

Comment: It does answer your question. You can not marry a Hindu until she accepts Islam.

Comment: The conversion must be genuine for the sake of Allah, not for the sake of marriage or a formality. Also a muslim practicing hinduism and islam at the same time will remove the person from islam as associating/worshipping partners other that Allah is shirk